# 100% height CSS, Fixed footer

Tags: html, css

My code is viewable at http://jsfiddle.net/ATbA5/2/  code will also be at the end of this post

I am trying to make content-wrapper 100% height however for it to be centered. I have looked at other theards on stackoverflow and Can't find a solution. Also A fixed footer at the end of the page not the bottom of the broswer window

HTML

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="primary-resources/css/main-styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
<div class="threetwentyleft">
<a href="index.html"><img src="primary-resources/imgs/header-logo.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="sixfortyright">
<div class="gameAdBanner">
<img src="game-resources/gameone/imgs/banner.png"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Content -->
<div class="gameLeft"></div>
<div class="gameRight"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body ,html {
    background-color:#000000;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    clear:both;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.content-wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:960px;
    padding:0px;
    bottom:0;px;
    top:0px;
    margin:auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    clear:both;
    box-sizing:border-box;

}
.header {
    width:100%;
}
.threetwentyleft {
    width:320px;
    float:left;
    padding:2px;
}
.threetwentyleft img{
    width:320px;
    padding:2px;
    border:0px;
}
.sixfortyright {
    width:630px;
    float:right;
    height:130px;
}
.gameAdBanner {
    width:610px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.center {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.gameLeft {
    width:700px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
}
.gameRight {
    width:260px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    float:right;
    padding:5px;
    height:100%;
    margin-right:3px;
}
.footer {
    width:960px;
    background-color:#FC6;
    bottom:0px;
    height:25px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: with "at the end of the page" you mean on the right side?

Comment: @caramba The code labeled HTML and CSS after the question

Comment: there is no footer in your html (and no element with a class="center" which is in the css)

Comment: What do you mean by: "Also a fixed footer at the end of the page not the bottom of the browser window."  If the footer is at the end of the page, but the page is 100% of window height, then where does the footer go?

Comment: To make an element 100% high, even if it has no content, which would ensure this, you'll need to set `height: 100%;` on all parent elements of the element in question (in your case html and body).

Comment: @MarcAudet If the page overflows I want the footer to appear at the very end of the page, not at the end of the broswer window. So

----SCREEN----
---CONTENT----
---CONTENT---
--END OF BROSWER WINDOW---
--CONTENT---
--CONTENT---
--FOOTER--

Comment: What about the case of a short page where the content would not be tall enough to fill the page, where do you want the footer to be?

Comment: @MarcAudet at the end of the page, however the content container is 100% so it would appear at the bottom. However 100% height is not working atm with the container

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want normal html behaviour, no need for any css, just add a div, or any block element after the content.